# Elasticsearch Completion Suggetser

Tags: elasticsearch

We are a bit confused as to the behavior of the Completion Suggester.
Say for example we provide 2 inputs to the Suggester:
"Hello World" and "Goodbye World"

Also assume that we have specified the Standard Analyzer for the Completion field.

Does this mean that the 2 inputs will create 3 terms i.e. "hello", "goodbye" and "world" and will entering a prefix for any one these bring up a successful suggestion?

It seems not. If we enter "world", we get no suggestion?

Why is that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default, for the completion suggester to return anything, the input you search for must match the tokens from the left to the right.

```
{
  "suggest" : ["Hello World"]
}
```

So, if you input `hel` or `hell` or `hello` then you'll get the `Hello World` suggestion.

You can change this behavior, by adding some [more possible inputs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#indexing) to your completion field:

```
{
  "suggest" : [ "Hello World", "World" ]
}
```

In this case, `Hello World` would also match if you input only `World`. It's up to you to decide what the valid suggestions should be for your documents.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So what is the point of specifying an analyzer. For example if you specify a standard analyzer which has a standard tokenizer, that is supposed ti break up the input into terms otherwise why is their the option of providing an analyzer specifically for the completion field.

Comment: The default analyzer of the completion field is the `simple` analyzer which ignores numbers. So if the data you're indexing contains numbers (e.g. phone numbers, license plates, etc), then it makes sense to provide a different analyzer. However, judging by what you're describing it doesn't seem like you need a completion field (i.e. you. don't need positional matching), a simple `text` one with the `standard` analyzer would probably do the job.

Comment: Hi. Why when we assign a Standard analyzer to the completion field, does it not tokenize it and only accepts prefixes of the start of each input? Where is the tokenization? That is our confusion. Thanks

Comment: There's a misunderstanding about what the standard analyzer does, it does not provide prefix-type support. And the aim of the completion suggester is to provide fast prefix suggestions... maybe you should better explain what you're after and what your use case is and we'll find an adequate solution